# Identity ASP.NET Core, erro "Cannot create a DbSet for 'Usuario' because this type is not included in the model for the context"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, pgadmin4

estou começando a aprender o Asp.Net Core, e estou tento um problema quanto a um cadastro de usuário, pois quando tento criar me retorna um erro interno com a mensagem "Cannot create a DbSet for 'Usuario' because this type is not included in the model for the context"

Meu codigo está assim,

**Startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<RotaPontoServico>();
        services.AddScoped<RotaServico>();

        services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<Context>(opt =>
           opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyWebApiConnection")));

          services.AddDefaultIdentity<Usuario>()              
                     .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>()
                     .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(opt =>
        {
            opt.GroupNameFormat = "'V'VVV";
            opt.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
        })
        .AddApiVersioning(opt => {
            opt.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            opt.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            opt.ReportApiVersions = true;
        });

        var apiProviderderDescription = services.BuildServiceProvider()
                                                .GetService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>  {
            foreach (var description in apiProviderderDescription.ApiVersionDescriptions)
            {
                x.SwaggerDoc(
                    description.GroupName,
                    new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo()
                    {
                        Title = "AppLudis",
                        Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString()
                    }
                    );
            }
            x.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "JWT Authorization header usando o esquema bearer",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
            }
                );
            x.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {new OpenApiSecurityScheme{Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Id = "Bearer",
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                }}, new List<string>()}
            });

            var xmlCommentsFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlCommentsFullPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlCommentsFile);
            x.IncludeXmlComments(xmlCommentsFullPath);
        });
        services.AddControllers();                    
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: "CargaViewer", configurePolicy: builder => builder.RequireClaim("carga.view", allowedValues: "true"));
            //options.AddPolicy("embarcador", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Store", "embarcador"));
        });

        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);

        services.AddAuthentication(X =>
        {
            X.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            X.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(X =>
        {
            X.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            X.SaveToken = true;
            X.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = appSettings.ValidoEm,
                ValidIssuer = appSettings.Emissor
            };
        });
        services.AddControllers();

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                          IWebHostEnvironment env,
                          IApiVersionDescriptionProvider apiProviderderDescription)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(opt =>
        {
            foreach (var description in apiProviderderDescription.ApiVersionDescriptions)
            {
                opt.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
            }
            opt.RoutePrefix = "";

        });

        app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

**Context**

```
public class Context : IdentityDbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) :
base(options)
    { } 
   // public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Esportista> Esportistas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comerciante> Comerciantes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Rota> RotaDb { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RotaPonto> RotaPontoDb { get; set; }

    public DbSet<IdentityUser> Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

**RegisterUserViewModels**

```
 public class RegisterUserViewModels
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} está em formato inválido")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} precisa ter entre {2} e {1} caracteres", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "As senhas não conferem.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

}

public class LoginUserViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} está em formato inválido")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} precisa ter entre {2} e {1} caracteres", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
 private readonly SignInManager<Usuario> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<Usuario> _userManager;
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public UsuarioController(SignInManager<Usuario> signInManager,
                          UserManager<Usuario> userManager,
                          IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }

    [HttpPost("nova-conta")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Registrar(RegisterUserViewModels registerUser)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState.Values.SelectMany(e => e.Errors));

        var newUseId = Guid.NewGuid();

        var user = new Usuario

        {

            Id = newUseId.ToString(),
            UserName = registerUser.Email,
            Email = registerUser.Email,
            EmailConfirmed = true
           /* Telefone = registerUser.Telefone,
            Endereco = registerUser.Endereco,
            CEP = registerUser.CEP,
            Cidade = registerUser.Cidade,
            Bairro = registerUser.Bairro,
            Nome = registerUser.Nome,
            Complemento = registerUser.Complemento,
            UF = registerUser.UF,
            IdEsportista = registerUser.IdEsportista,
            IdComerciante = registerUser.IdComerciante*/


        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, registerUser.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded) return BadRequest(result.Errors);

        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);

        await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(type: "carga.view", value: "true"));


        return Ok(await GerarJwt(registerUser.Email));
    }
```

o erro está acontencendo na linha "var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, registerUser.Password);"

Comment: Já experimentou descomentar `// public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }`?

Comment: Está linha está documentada pois nos exemplos que vi não utilizava, então comentei. Mas tentei também e o erro mudou agora dá "column a.Discriminator does not exist" estou tentando achar este a.Disriminator